# Symfony kernel.controller event send response

Tags: httprequest, symfony, httpresponse

as far as I read the Symfony-Documentation i can't find anything about the response handling in the `kernel.controller` event.

For the `kernel.request` event the documentation says:

> If a Response is returned at this stage, the process skips directly to the kernel.response event.

But what about the `kernel.controller` event?
If I'm returning a response in the `kernel.controller` event listener the response is sent to the client but the process isn't canceled and the requested controller action is called.

Is it possible to send a response within the `kernel.controller` event without proceeding to the requested controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indirectly, you can by changing the controller in the FilterControllerEvent.

You can use any callable as a controller, given that it returns a Response object in the end. In your event listener, you could for example do the following:

```
$event->setController(function() {
    return new Response();
});
```

Of course you can return any kind of response in your controller.

Comment: Oh okay, so this callable function is my "controller" and returns a response. Is this the way to go? Or is there some other best practice to avoid calling the controller after the `kernel.controller` event?

Comment: Wether or not this is the way to go depends on your specific usecase, which I do not know. But this is the way to prevent the default controller to be executed in a kernel.controller event, apart from throwing an exception.